# Creating a 3D printable terrain model with blender

Tags: 3d-printing

Hi dear fellow blenders!

I am trying to create a 3D printable model of an existing nature protected area in Germany and kind of hit a wall since i am very new to blender and 3D modelling.

The end result should look like this (apart from my model only having one texture on the up side):

[image]

What i did so far:

1. - creating a plane with the dimensions of roughly 40x40x1.2 cm.
   - subdividing the plane by 500 and adding a displacement modifier to mold  the surface of the plane into the shape of the actual relief.
   - applying a texture using the aerial photo of the area

so far so good. as far as i know, i need to modify this plane to make it an actual 3d printable object. i would like to have it look like in the first picture but being kind of a hollow cube with a relief on the up side to minimize the costs.

so i thought i would create another plane with the same dimensions, place it underneath the first plane, subdivide 500 times like i did with the first and finally join the vertices along the edges. in addition i would solidify both planes using the modifier.

now i solidified the first plane (unfortunately i can't post the picture)

i actually have the feeling that this is not the result i had in mind, since it seems like only the rim of the plane got solidified as can be seen in the picture. i don't seem to actually have created thickness.

after adding the second plane, positioning and solidifying it i got this result:

[image]

and now i hit the wall. i assume that one way to proceed would be to build the four "sides" of the cube by connecting the vertices along the rim since they mirror each other (because i subdivided both planes 500 times and located them parallel to each other).

how would i connect the vertices in blender?

what would be the quickest way to achieve the intended end result?

I am completely new to blender and assume that the result could be achieved fairly quickly, but i don't know how and i am not sure if my intended method would actually be the best method to achieve the result...

has anyone experience in creating printable 3d reliefs in blender who could point me in the right direction?

thanks in advance,

Hannes

Comment: There is something I don't understand about the initial plane : why the border (which can be seen front in the screen shot) is not flat ?

Comment: @lemon i am pretty sure that the border is flat...it must be some kind of optical illusion caused by the texture.    thanks for your advice, lemon. i also thought extruding would be the best way, but after extruding the bottom side of the plane has the negative relief of the up side and does not have an even base. can you give me a more precise description how to get a flat base after extruding? thanks for your quick reply! :)

Comment: Can you upload the relief/displacement map (this will be easier to show for an answer) ?

Comment: @lemon: [This](http://i.imgur.com/tDkJKB8.png) is the view on the bottom side with deactivated texture. i hope this helps. i guess the visual effect along the borders is caused by the displacement, but i am pretty sure its straight. what bothers me is the base...

Comment: ok... from the first base plane (which is displaced), apply the displace modifier. Then edit mode, select all and extrude it Z to the bottom. Then scale Z 0 these newly extruded vertices

Comment: @lemon i am not entirely sure what you exactly mean by "extrude it Z to the bottom". do you mean i should keep the second plain plane and extrude the initial plane so that they touch? i am still a bit lost with all the different buttons in blender. i hope it is not to much to ask if you could post a screenshot highlighting which buttons and fields i exactly need to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Starting from the displaced plane
- Apply the displace modifier
- Enter edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Select all <kbd>A</kbd>
- Place yourself in front (<kbd>NumPad1</kbd>) ortho view (<kbd>NumPad5</kbd> if needed)
- Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd>
- Now scale along Z to zero to flatten the base : <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>0</kbd>

Note: all keystrokes are not visible in the gif as 500 subdivisions is a bit too much on my computer. But the keys are written above (and you can see the operations on the bottom left of the screen)

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply and your efforts. i hate admitting that despite your description something is off with my project and i do not achieve the desired results. it begins with the first step of displacing. if i use the same values of midlevel and strength as you did i get a really  [weird and distorted shape](http://i.imgur.com/rMd1lUs.png). so instead i went with  [this shape and these values](http://i.imgur.com/JfEQcnx.png) although this shape corresponds with the shape i have prior to displacing. you might also notice in these screenshots the concave deformation of my sides.

Comment: @HannesD,  did you applied the displace modifier before extruding ?

Comment: when [extruding](http://i.imgur.com/SjT4HT5.png) i can only extrude upwards and not towards the black area. i assume that is intentional. [this](http://i.imgur.com/xYKADM7.png) is what happens when i scale along Z to 0. in the end the shape looks a lot like before and still has relief on both sides. i notice that in edit mode the color fading from orange to black is reversed compared to yours... so i am doing something wrong, but i have no clue what... :(

Comment: i have to admit that despite my research i do not understand the purpose of the displacement (the one you described, not the initial one...)

Comment: @HannesD. again, you need to apply the modifier **before** extruding (there is other mean to do it without applying but this is not the point here)

Comment: @HannesD., if you have performance issue (like I had with the 500 subdiv), have a try on this process using less subdiv in order to see clearly how it can work

Comment: (it took me too long to write the comment, that's why i didn't see your reply in the meantime...) so just to make sure. i loaded an earlier file now, since i extruded the other plane once before. now my plane is fresh and clean again and all that happened so far was the initial displacement for the relief and application of texture. however when i now displace exactly like you did, the relief changes and the hills get distoreted into some kind of [bubbly shape](http://i.imgur.com/t9MHbq0.png). is this correct? or i should just neglect it?

Comment: @HannesD., at the step we are.. you may share your blend file (editing your question). So that someone can have the same starting point as you have. This will not be me, as it is late here, but that does not matter...

Comment: yes, it is also late here and i am a little too frustrated to keep on trying today. if you'd be willing to look at my file it would be awesome, since i am running low on time and this is a project for my studies. would you be willing to have a look? then let me know how i could get the file to you....

Comment: just wanted to thank you for your help. your method worked! the problem was that i still had a previous modifier in my stack that i hadn't applied yet (the first displacer). so yeah, problem solved!